# Is Inflation modelled by a field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

If Inflation is modelled by a field - is this a classical field or a quantum field? If classical are there good reasons not to quantise it? What are the implications of such a quantisation?

Comment: It is assumed that inflation, both the early and the present one, can be modelled by one or more [inflaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29) fields. These are quantum fields and the quanta of these fields correspond to (at present not directly experimentally observed) particles.

Comment: It needs to be quantized to have introduce fluctuations in the model.